# kdb how to remove string key from dictionary

Tags: kdb

I am having difficulty removing an entry from KDB dictionary. Keys and values are strings.

**Working**

```
q)l3:`a`b`c!1 2 3
q)`a _l3
b| 2
c| 3
```

**Not working**

```
q)l2:("k1";"k2";"ABC")!("v1";"v2";"BLA BLA")
q)"k1" _l2
'type
```

Thanks,
Eugene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since type of "key list" in your dictionary is 0h  (mixed list or list of list)

```
     q) type ("k1";"k2";"ABC")
     q) 0h
```

and type of your single key is 10h (string)

```
     q)  type "k1"
     q) 10h
```

Thats why on matching, kdb gives you type error.
Reference: http://code.kx.com/q4m3/5_Dictionaries/

It says: 
 "The left operand of delete is the dictionary (target) and the right operand is a key value whose type matches that of target."

You can use following to remove the entry:

```
      q)   (k@where not (k:key l2) like "k1")#l2

Key Value
k2  v2
ABC BLA BLA
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Key point you made is that string keys are list[list].

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use `enlist` to drop the string key from dictionary:

```
q)enlist["k1"]_("k1";"k2";"ABC")!("v1";"v2";"BLA BLA")
"k2" | "v2"
"ABC"| "BLA BLA"
```

`_`(drop) takes left input as list of elements of the dictionary key (with exception when it comes to symbol key). Try to imagine that in your case, "k1" is an 'atom' and to create a singleton list, you can just `enlist` "k1".

Reference: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#_-cut

Comment: "k1" is itself a list (string).  'enlist "k1"' will  convert this list to type 0h and hence it will work as 'key l2' has type 0h in Vortex example.